# Refresh Data - Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I am using Sharepoint List and OData Feed for my Power BI reports using import. What I want to accomplish is that my power bi desktop to get updated data and publish to power bi service even if I'm not around. Is it possible? I have a colleague who can refresh it for me but the logic is that he'll be creating a new power bi project service (I think).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot schedule a report to refresh in Power BI Desktop, you have to do it via a manual process.

You will need to publish the report to the Power BI Service, you can then set a [refresh schedule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/refresh-scheduled-refresh) there and the report will refresh automatically from your data source. You will not have to recreate the report or upload it again one it is there.

Comment: okay, gateway is now good to go. However; I can't edit credentials on my sharepoint list. I am only getting Anonymous as authentication method while my power bi desktop is in windows credentials and organizational privacy level.

Answer (score 0):

First publish your Power BI desktop to Power BI Services, which will enable auto refresh.
Power BI has direct connectors for SharePoint so you can set schedule auto refresh. And for connecting SharePoint OnPrem you can use Data connectors.